# How to take the user's input through a text field when somebody types a certain sentence?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement

So, I put a text field that is supposed to take commands from the user, kind of like a virtual assistant. When the user types in "My name is (insert a name here)" I want the variable userName to get what's written after "My name is..." I've looked through the Internet for solutions but no use...
It keeps alerting me "idk".

```
var userName = "";
var userResponse = document.getElementById("virtual_assistant_body_form_input");
var userResponseField = document.getElementById("virtual_assistant_body_form_input_text_message_field").value; // Selects the field element from the form element.
userResponse.onsubmit = function() { 
    if (userResponseField.includes('My name is') === true) {
        var userName = userResponseField.substr(9, 999);
        alert(userName);
    }
    else {
        alert("idk");
    }
};
```

Comment: You need to get the `value` AFTER submit. Remove `.value` from `userResponseField` and inside `onsubmit`, use `userResponseField.value.includes` and `userResponseField.value.substr`

Comment: It's been that simple!? Thank you so much! Is there any way I can thank you by raising a reputation or something?

Comment: You can either delete it since it was a small mistake and it's unlikely to help any future readers. Or, if you think it's useful you can accept one of the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you read the empty form field first and store its value instead of getting the current value on submit. So move it like this:

```
var userName = "";
var userResponse = document.getElementById("virtual_assistant_body_form_input");
userResponse.onsubmit = function() { 
    var userResponseField = document.getElementById("virtual_assistant_body_form_input_text_message_field").value; // Selects the field element from the form element.
    if (userResponseField.includes('My name is') === true) {
        var userName = userResponseField.substr(9, 999);
        alert(userName);
    }
    else {
        alert("idk");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that you're grabbing the input value before submit, so the value stored in tour variable `userResponseField` is not up to date, it doesn't contain the name.

The code below can be improved but I'm in the bus, let me knwo if it solves your issue.

```
let userName = '';
const inputText = 'My name is ';
const userResponse = document.getElementById('virtual_assistant_body_form_input');
function getUserResponseField() {
    return document.getElementById('virtual_assistant_body_form_input_text_message_field').value;;
}
userResponse.onsubmit = function() {
    const responseField = getUserResponseField(); // Grabbing the name at this stage, not before
    if (responseField.includes(inputText)) {
        userName = responseField.replace(inputText, '');
        alert(userName);
    }
    else {
        alert('idk');
    }
};
```